# Inserir Imagem e musica num projeto c++

Tags: c++

Olá, qual a biblioteca que permite eu inserir imagens e musicas num projeto de c++? A bilbioteca SDL2 permite? 
Neste momento tenho o snake game a correr apenas na consola, mas gostava de colocar uma imagem de fundo, algo mais engraçado.

Obrigado e cumprimentos

Comment: Pra jogos (o seu caso), a `sdl2` atende bem as necessidades, possui suporte pra imagens e música, como quer. Vou deixar esses links para servir de guia para começar a pesquisar: [música](https://adamtcroft.com/playing-sound-with-sdl-c/), [imagem](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/), e esse [guia](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) especificamente para jogos.

Comment: Hum ok, vou vendo esses tutoriais então, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim o SDL permite tudo isso, gráficos 2D/3D, som, imagem, etc. Com ele você pode reproduzir sons simples como [este exemplo](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideaudioexamples.html), mas se quiser reproduzir faixas de áudio como mp3 você precisara utilizar o [SDL_Mixer](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/), exemplo de utilização do mixer: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson11/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma biblioteca bem interessante chamada Allegro. É possível fazer tudo que você deseja, inclusive trabalhar com os movimentos do cenário de uma maneira bem didática. Tem vários tutoriais no youtube sobre esse biblioteca.

Segue o link: https://liballeg.org/

Abraço.